# Debugging a Custom Windows.Forms.ComboBox

Tags: winforms, combobox

**Problem** - whenever I set a custom ComboBox to "ON," it will change to "ON" momentarily, but it will then occasionally switch to "OFF."

Basically I have a method:

```
void value_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   if((ComboBox)sender.Focused == true)
    {
      if(value.SelectedIndex == false) // OFF
         // set a bunch of variables for OFF
      else // ON
         // set a bunch of variables for ON
    }
}
```

After I set the ComboBox to "ON," it then executes the code path for "ON" selected index. But then, the selected index switches to "OFF," for a reason I do not understand. As a result, the OFF variables code path then executes.

To attempt to fix it, I put a log statement to capture the sender and EventArgs e whenever this "value_SelectedIndexChanged" method gets called. However the sender equals the class and the EventArgs is System.EventArgs.

Please advise me on how to debug this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand why you structure your code that way. Wouldn't it make more sense this way:

```
void value_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  switch(value.SelectedIndex)
  {
    case 0: // OFF
       // set a bunch of variables for OFF
       break;
    case 1: // ON
       // set a bunch of variables for ON
       break;
  }
}
```

The problem might be caused by the "set a bunch of variables for OFF"-actions. Have you tested that by setting a breakpoint in the handler and then stepping through everything?

Comment: Simon, I had stepped through the code for setting the OFF variables. However, I didn't see any code that would've changed the value's selectedIndex. I'm not too familiar with GUIs. What typically triggers a change in a selectedIndex?

Comment: Also, I don't entirely understand the first if-statement that checks if the ComboBox is focused. I agree that your code is *clear.

Comment: Changing the selection by any means will change the SelectedIndex property. So it could be caused by changing the data backing the ComboBox, changing the SelectedItem property or some other things.

Adding a breakpoint and single-stepping over the end of the method might give you some clues as to what causes the second change.

Comment: I haven't yet solved the issue, but here's what I've gathered. The code above lives in a event that gets called when the ComboBox changes values. Before the above event gets called, an event gets called because the original ComboBox code call gets another event registered to it. After I change the box from OFF to ON, it does the following: 1) call original ComboBox event with a value of ON 2) call the method above's event with a value of ON 3) call original ComboBox with a value of OFF 4) call method above's event with a value of OFF

Comment: Have you tried removing the other handler/listener? Also, can you try to create a small example showing the problem that you could post?